# iOS can't play audio while recording

Tags: ios

I'm working on the iOS AurioTouch2 demo. I wanna play a song while processing audio data. Here is the playing-audio code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FoldBeep" ofType:@"wav"];
SystemSoundID theSoundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &theSoundID);
```

I tried. It don't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: What category did you set your audio session to?  If you don't know what that means then you have not researched enough.

Comment: did you get this to play?